# How to open a Gradle wrapped project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, web-applications, gradle

I'm trying to open a web application project which is made using spring framework. But when I download the project it seems to be wrapped with Gradle.

[image]

Please guide me a way to open this project using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute `gradlew eclipse` to generate the needed eclipse files and then just import it with `Existing Project into Workspace`

Comment: so do i need to have gradle install on my machine?

Comment: The project contains the gradle wrapper so you can execute it from the project folder without any installation.